# Is there a utility to verify the checksums of every Windows file?

Tags: windows-7, security, checksum

I would like to know if there is a utility to verify the checksums of every Windows file on my Windows 7 Ultimate system. It seems on the surface such an obvious utility but I don't ever remember seeing one?

I had a very weird experience while surfing earlier today and now Im not entirely sure my system is secure. I have a collection of tools in the WSCC suite but these tools no doubt just make system calls to the win32 api and if that has been subverted then the tools are practically useless.

#### How do I know my Windows 7 files are actually Windows 7 files?

I am particularly interested in verifying the integrity of all network TCP/IP files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sfc /scannow`

> System File Checker is a utility in Microsoft Windows that allows users to scan for and restore corruptions in Windows system files. This utility is available on Windows 98, Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003. Windows Vista, although in the Windows NT family of operating systems, scans files using Windows Resource Protection.
>
> — http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_File_Checker